# Who invented the gradient?

Tags: calculus

Who is responsible for coming up with the gradient and why did they do so? In which work was it first described?

I have Googled this extensively, to no avail, and [Boyer's History of Calculus](https://archive.org/details/TheHistoryOfTheCalculusAndItsConceptualDevelopment) does not appear to contain the answer to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see [Nabla symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla_symbol#History) as well as [VECTOR CALCULUS SYMBOLS](http://jeff560.tripod.com/calculus.html) :

> The vector differential operator, now written $\nabla$ and called *nabla* or *del*, was introduced by [William Rowan Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Rowan_Hamilton) (1805-1865). Hamilton wrote the operator as a [90°] rotated nabla and it was [P.G.Tait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Tait_(physicist)) who established $\nabla$ as the conventional symbol; see his [An Elementary Treatise on Quaternions](https://archive.org/details/anelementarytre03taitgoog) (1867). Tait was also responsible for establishing the term *nabla*.

See also :

- [Josiah Willard Gibbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josiah_Willard_Gibbs) & [Edwin Bidwell Wilson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Bidwell_Wilson), [Vector analysis; a text-book for the use of students of mathematics and physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Analysis) (1901), e.g [page 138](https://archive.org/details/vectoranalysiste00gibbiala) :

> The vector sum which is the resultant rate of increase of $V$ is denoted by $\nabla V$.
>
> $\nabla V$ represents a directed rate of change of $V$ - a directed or vector derivative of $V$, so to speak. For this reason $\nabla V$ will be called the *derivative* of $V$; and $V$, the *primitive* of $\nabla V$. The terms *gradient* and *slope* of $V$ are also used for $\nabla V$.