# Who invented the gradient descent algorithm?

Tags: mathematics, calculus, linear-algebra

In connection to the question "[Who invented the gradient?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/who-invented-the-gradient)", I want to know who invented the gradient descent algorithm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "gradient descent" algorithm was invented before the gradient. It is described in equivalent form by Cauchy in a 3-page paper in Comptes Rendus, [Méthode générale pour la résolution des systèmes d'équations simultanées (1847)](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/cgi-bin/oeitem?id=OE_CAUCHY_1_10_399_1). Here is an [English translation](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~y328yu/classics/cauchy-en.pdf). A good secondary source is [Cauchy and the Gradient Method by Lemaréchal](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/documenta/vol-ismp/40_lemarechal-claude.pdf), who comments:

> "*Cauchy is motivated by astronomic calculations which, as everybody knows,
>   are normally very voluminous. To compute the orbit of a heavenly body, he
>   wants to solve "not the differential equations, but the [algebraic] equations rep-
>   resenting the motion of this body, taking as unknowns the elements of the orbit
>   themselves". To solve a system of equations in those days, "one ordinarily starts by reducing them to a single one by successive eliminations, to eventually solve for good the resulting equation, if possible. But it is important to observe that 1◦ in many
>   cases, the elimination cannot be performed in any way; 2◦ the resulting equation
>   is usually very complicated, even though the given equations are rather simple".
>   Something else is wanted.*"

Instead of the gradient vector Cauchy simply works with the partial derivatives $X=f'_x,Y=f'_y,Z=f'_z,...$. He takes small $\theta$, sets up the equation
$$\Theta=f(X-\theta x, Y-\theta y, Z-\theta z,...),$$
and, in one of the variants, recommends finding $\theta$ from $\Theta'_\theta=0$.

> [...] *One iteration of the gradient method is thus stated, with two variants: (2) (Armijo-type line-search) or (3) (steepest descent)... Convergence is just sloppily mentioned... Cauchy does not seem to believe that the method always finds a solution; yet, he also seems to hope it: see the excerpt of foot
>   note 4. Anyway a simple picture reveals that the least-squares function in (4) may display positive local minima, playing the role of “parasitic” solutions.
>   On the other hand, he seems convinced that, being decreasing, the sequence of
>   u-values has to converge to a (local) minimum, or at least a stationary point.
>   Thus, the above excerpt is fairly interesting, coming from a mathematician
>   among the most rigorous of his century. Admittedly, Cauchy has not given
>   deep thought to the problem: "I’ll restrict myself here to outlining the principles
>   underlying [my method], with the intention to come again over the same subject,
>   in a paper to follow". However, the “paper to follow” does not seem to exist.*"

See also related post [Who invented stochastic gradient descent? on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/313681/250912).